# How to get the text showed under eachother?

Tags: javascript, html-table

How to show the text not next but under each other like a list?

```
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode("1x1= 1");
  var cellText1 = document.createTextNode("1x2= 2");
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  cell.appendChild(cellText1);
  row.appendChild(cell);

}
```

like:

1 x 1 = 1

1 x 2 = 2

Comment: Use an unordered list `<ul>`

Comment: Alternatively you could add `<br>` after every line. It's probably a bit dirty though.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are your friend:

```
var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    li.text = "1x1=5";
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

//Append ul to a container now
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ul` instead of `table`:

```
<ul id="result">
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add(n) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        var el = document.createElement("li");
        var val = document.createTextNode(i + " * " + i + " = " + (Math.pow(i,2)));
        el.appendChild(val);
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(el);
    }
}

add(5);
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3KGPq/2/)